SAS Proc SQL Encoding Issue
I was trying to create a table that may contain some special characters, which keeps resulting in the error:
ERROR: Open error: Failed to transcode result set data in column 'X', row 296, to SESSION encoding. Use the SUBCHAR= LIBNAME/DATA SET option to resolve transcoding issues.
Following are the codes I used to create the table. I have tried to add (SUBCHAR=UESC) to the create table line but it's not working. I'm very sure that the issue is coming from the column contains some special characters or punctuations, but have no idea how to do the configuration on SAS. Appreciate any help that can help me complete the configuration to read or simply ignore the special characters.
Proc SQL;
CONNECT TO HADOOP(SERVER="...");
create table work.Temp as
SELECT *
FROM CONNECTION TO HADOOP
(
these are SQL codes... can ignore
)
;
disconnect from Hadoop;
quit;

I don't mind ignoring those special characters, but right now the whole table cannot be created because of that error.
